# Execution Timeout Expired. Error while retrieving account details

Tags: acumatica

Currently the error is happening when we try to select a particular account in the Finance > GL >Explore > Account Details.

We have encountered this error previously in Acumatica and we were able to extend the time out by setting the web config value. But this time, it seems like not working. As even after setting the timeout to 300, the page is throwing exception within 2 minutes or so.

> httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"

Is there anything else need to be checked?

Answer (score 2):

This requires the Query time out to be configured

To [Configure](http://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=62b4944b-22d6-48d6-955d-f672b8ba1057) the Query Time-Out

Add the queryTimeout parameter to the line and specify the query timeout time (in seconds).

```
 <add name="PXSqlDatabaseProvider" type="PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider,
 PX.Data" ... queryTimeout="100" />
```